# DataDog link custom spans and web spans in Azure AppService

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, datadog, azure-appservice

We have a VM with DataDogAgent in azure, on this VM we host `ASP.Net core API` application. We collect these kind of metrics:

- web requests metrics collected from environment by `DataDogAgent`
- custom spans collected from the `C#` application code with help of `DataDog.Trace`.

Here is the code of stub API:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {

        using (var dd1 = Tracer.Instance.StartActive("test-custom-measure1"))
        using(var dd2 = Tracer.Instance.StartActive("test-custom-measure2"))
        {
            Task.Delay(100).Wait();
        }
    }
```

In data dog dashboard these 2 kind of metrics are stacked together for one request into one trace:
[image]

After application migrated to `Azure AppService`(`.NET Datadog APM` is used to collect metrics here), spans are not stacked into one trace and appears in dashborad as separate traces.

[image]

How to merge them into one trace in `Azure App Service`?